# Ignore a previous version of boost C++

Tags: c++, boost, linker, boost-thread

I have to give a demo on a machine which contains an old version of the C++ boost library. Specifically I need `boost::thread`, in which I am using the `lock` member function of the `mutex` class. Unfortunately the old version (1.33.1) does not contain this method.

I don't have root access on the target machine, and I can't uninstall the previous version of boost. My solution was to pre-compile the updated library on the target machine and just link to the newer version of the library.

The library-compiling part went great, everything went off without a hitch, but when I tried to compile it still indicated that it was using the old version of boost. I did a bit of looking around (g++ noob here) and found out that you can manually specify a location to look for headers and libraries first using the `-L` and `-I` flags. I tried to use these with relative paths (since I don't know the directory from which the demo will be executed but I do know the relative path to my new boost libraries) and I came up with this:

```
-bash-3.2$ g++ -I./include -L./lib main.cpp -lthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lthread
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've been trying all kinds of stuff, such as specifying a path deeper into the include/library directories, but with no luck, and I feel like I'm at a dead end. Any ideas?
FYI, I'm looking to use boost 1.49.0.

Comment: Do you have libthread.so in ./lib?

Comment: ./lib contains the following files: `libboost_thread.a`,  `libboost_thread.so`, and `libboost_thread.so.1.49.0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
g++ -I./include -L./lib main.cpp -lboost_thread
```

The name of the library you need to specify for `-l` is derived from the `.so` file: leave off the beginning `lib` and the `.so` (e.g. `libboost_thread.so` -> `-lboost_thread`)

Comment: It probably was compiled with a different configuration setting than the one installed on the system.  Look up the parameters for the BOOST build process

Comment: Oh spoke too soon: now when I run the executable I get the error *error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.49.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the linux environment, but I think you will need to set one of the environmental variables so the executable can find the shared library (try PATH first: `export PATH=$PATH:./lib`)

Comment: Actually it seems like you need [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html)